# URL Hack on Dependent Picklist field in Lightning

Tags: lightning, urlhacking, dependent-picklist

I'm trying to clone a Case, for that, I have created a button to copy data from the parent Case. I have a dependent picklist field(`Experience__c`) on the Case object. It is dependent on `Product_Type__c`. The dependent field is not getting populated with the value.

Any help is much appreciated. I read the issue is fixed in previous releases. But dont see its working for me.

The button URL is:

`/lightning/o/Case/new?defaultFieldValues=ParentId={!Case.Id},Product_Type__c={!Case.Product_Type__c},Experience__c={!Case.Experience__c}`

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible for **Cases**.

In Summer '21, they brought the ability to [prepopulate dependent picklists with default values](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_default_value_dependent_picklist.htm&type=5&release=232) for a specified list of objects

> You can now prepopulate a record event with default values in
> dependent picklists. **Default values on dependent picklists are
> available on accounts, opportunities, contacts, leads, and custom
> objects.**

You'll have to look at a different mechanism for this - possibly a screen flow where you can set default values for the dependent picklist or leveraging a LWC with [recordEditForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation). Otherwise, you could tackle this from the other side with a record-triggered flow to copy over the parent Case's picklist values if it's left empty if you do want to leverage the button URL or a quick action that also cannot set [pre-defined field values for dependent picklists](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.predefined_field_values_notes.htm&type=5).